# mysql grouping select lmost recent date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select the most recent date per PropertyId and Type from the sample table below.

```
|PropertyId | Type | ExpiryDate
|1          |1     | 2017-01-20

|1          |1     | 2016-01-20  

|1          |2     | 2017-01-20

|1          |2     | 2016-01-20

|2          |1     | 2017-01-20

|2          |1     | 2016-01-20

|2          |2     | 2017-01-20

|2          |2     | 2016-01-20
```

So would be looking for the result :-

```
|PropertyId | Type | ExpiryDate

|1          |1     | 2017-01-20

|1          |2     | 2017-01-20

|2          |1     | 2017-01-20

|2          |2     | 2017-01-20
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use group by

```
SELECT max(ExpiryDate),PropertyId , Type  from Table group by PropertyId , Type;
```

Comment: Thats Fabulous thank you.

Comment: How would i be able to select only the rows where the expiry date is greater than today

Comment: add following at the end of the query : having date(now())< ExpiryDate